# How does symmetry act on general case fermionic operator?

Tags: symmetry, hamiltonian, fermions, topology, tight-binding

I am trying to understand symmetries and how they work in condensed matter physics to understand some concepts from topology.

In general second-qunatized Hamiltionian can be written in the following way:
$$\hat{H} = \sum_{ij}\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}_{I}h_{ij}\hat{\Psi}_{j}.$$
Now I am trying to understand how symmetries act on "first-quantized" hamiltionian $h_{ij}$.
I know that we need apply some symmetry, let's say time-reversal $\hat{T}$ to $\hat{H}$ and assuming we have time-reversal Hamiltionian, we should get the same Hamiltonian  $\hat{H}$.

But what I don't understand, is how do we have to apply this operator $\hat{T}$ to general case Fermionic operator $\hat{\Psi}_i$.
What about other symmetries, like particle-hole or chiral, is there some recipe to see how the symmetry changes $\hat{\Psi}_i$ and thus $h_{ij}$.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) you should apply $\mathcal T$ operator to wavefunctions, so that:

$$ \hat{\mathcal T}\hat{H} = \sum_{ij} \hat {\mathcal T} \langle \hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}_{i} | \hat{\mathcal T}h_{ij}|\hat{\Psi}_{j} \rangle \tag 1$$

Because time reversal operator is anti-linear, we get :

$$ \hat{\mathcal T}\hat{H} = \sum_{ij} \hat {\mathcal T} \langle  \hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}_{i} | h_{ij}^\dagger \hat{\mathcal T}|\hat{\Psi}_{j} \rangle \tag 2$$

Now according to [this lecture](https://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Excchen/img/Ph129b2020/lecture/lecture0312.pdf), time reversal operator makes some unitary transformation to complex conjungated wavefunction, that is :
$$ \mathcal T \psi =  U \psi ^\dagger \tag 3 $$

Knowing this we can re-write (2) as  :

$$ \hat{\mathcal T}\hat{H} = \sum_{ij} \langle  \hat{\Psi}_{i} | U^{\dagger}h_{ij}^\dagger U|\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}_{j} \rangle \tag 4$$

From this point, you are on your own to resolve further unitary transformations.  For simple cases though, like if we would like to apply time reversal to [Schrodinger equation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-x9_pyWLZl0),- it would just perform complex conjugate on both equation sides, but in your case I'm afraid unitary transformations are not canceled trivially.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book "Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors" by Bernevig, on page 34 you will find the answer.